# simple function not being reconized

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

the below function is generating the "x" is not a function error, for the love of me I have no idea why this is happening? any help is much appreciated.

```
  function updateShareholder() {

    var date = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    console.log('updateShareholder');
    var data = {
      companyID: agreement.applicant.applicantCompanyID,
      userID: agreement.coSigner.coSignerID,
      agreementID: agreement.agreement.agreementID,
      stock: agreement.stock.stock
    }
    company_worker.updateShareholder(data, function(err, result) {

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        console.log('updateShareholder');
        process.nextTick(function() {
          emailNotification()
        });
      }

    });

  };
```

if it helps here is the company worker function that is called within.

```
 module.exports.updateShareHolder = function(req, callback) {

  console.log('updateShareHolder');

  Company.update({
      "_id": req.companyID,
      "shareHolders.userId": req.userID
    }, {
      $push: {
        "shareHolders.$.agreements": {
          agreementID: req.agreementID
        }
      }
    }, {
      $set: {
        "shareHolders.$.shares": ++req.shares
      }
    },
    function(err) {

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err, err);
      } else {
        console.log('updateShareHolder');
        callback(null, 'success');
      }
    })
};
```

and this is the function that calls the so-called broken function

```
  function moveOn() {
    if (addShareHolder == 'true') {
      process.nextTick(function() {
        addShareholder()
      });
    } else if (updateShareholder == 'true') {
      process.nextTick(function() {
        updateTheShareholder()
      });
    }

  };
```

Comment: Please share the real error message, as this will give more info about your error that `x` is not a function. You also didn't show the `addShareholder()` function. How do your scopes look? Is everything accessible from the different pieces of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in the function name.

You are exporting `module.exports.updateShareHolder` and calling `company_worker.updateShareholder`. Notice the lowercase `h`,

Comment: thanks for picking that up. but the issue is still there the current issue is actually produced before i am calling the company_worker.     this is the error ------       ReferenceError: updateTheShareholder is not defined